# "Can't find table names in FROM clause" error with DBD::CSV

Tags: perl, csv, dbi

I'm trying to use a `UNION` statement in `DBI` to combine two CSV files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:") 
    or die "Cannot connect to the CSV file: $DBI::errstr()";
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
$dbh->{TraceLevel} = 0;

my $query = "select * from file.csv UNION select * from output.csv";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ();
$sth->dump_results();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

However, I get the following errors:

> Can't find table names in FROM clause! at
>   C:/Perl64/site/lib/SQL/Statement.pm line 88. 
> DBD::CSV::db prepare
>   failed: Can't find table names in FROM clause! at C:/Perl64
>   /site/lib/SQL/Statement.pm line 88.  
> [for Statement "select * from
>   file.csv UNION select * from output.csv"] at CSV. pl line 15.
>   DBD::CSV::db prepare failed: Can't find table names in FROM clause! at
>   C:/Perl64 /site/lib/SQL/Statement.pm line 88.  
> [for Statement "select
>   * from file.csv UNION select * from output.csv"] at CSV. pl line 15.

I updated `SQL::Statement` and `SQL::Parse` as suggested elsewhere but that didn't fix the issue. I'm running on Windows 8.1. What is causing the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Drop `.csv` extensions from query and make sure your files are in current dir:

```
my $query = "select * from file UNION select * from output";
```

You can also explicitly set folder with csv files,

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", "", "", {
    f_dir => 'C:\path_to_csv',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV-0.41/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) uses [SQL::Statement](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/SQL-Statement-1.405/lib/SQL/Statement.pm) as its SQL engine. SQL::Statement [only supports a subset of SQL commands](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/SQL-Statement-1.405/lib/SQL/Statement/Syntax.pod#Default_Supported_SQL_syntax_-_Summary), which does not include `UNION`.

As an alternative, why not simply concatenate the two files?